# Human Acid Blood

Tags: internal-consistency, society, alternate-reality

Inspired by this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N0jaxb94Fc), the question arose what today's society would look like if humans (Homo sapiens sapiens) had blood that is so acidic that it eats through all matter. The only exception to this is the human bloodstream (and a metal/stone deep under the earth, which is unknown (sorry but mass murder/suicide does not let the earth collapse)). Everything else is normal.  The human being is not restricted in his normal functioning (no injuries, no diseases) with the acidity in the blood.

As an example of what I have in mind, the fact that organ transplants are much more rare, because the organs (which are full of blood) can not be transported.
Historical events, in which people were given blood transfusions... by blood transfusion, I would ignore.

**I would just like to know what society would look like with acidic human blood in as many aspects as possible.**

Not needed:

-how history would have changed...

-or how the blood would develop acidity

**EDIT:**

the effects on daily life (e.g. if you have a 9-5 office job, family with 2 children,...) interest me the most, so you can

Ignore warfare, environmental disasters and other unusual things.

Comment: So is the rest of human bodies 100% immune to this acid-blood? If not a single scratch would cause massive acid burns. 


Something you should consider is that acid doesn't just "dissolve" through stuff like in cartoons. It breaks things down by reacting with them, using itself up in the process. A single drop of super-acid can't eat through 1 meter of concrete, for instance. 

Also the faster a reaction is, the more violent it tends to be. 

Some of the scariest acids we know about don't just melt things, they burst into flames and spew toxic vapors.

Comment: @abestrange only the blood vessels are immune to the acid but it can be assumed that the blood can close smaller wounds fast enough so that the surrounding tissue does not suffer irreparable damage. skin decomposes in longer contact ( ~5 min) with the blood 
I would equate the strength of the acid with the alien blood from the films

Comment: Greetings! Your query is far too broad to really be answered. You need to focus on a single aspect or problem of worldbuilding.  Please review the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how this forum works!

Answer (score 2):

Human life is messy and we often get blood everywhere. That includes internal bleeding as well as just bleeding all over the place. We HAVE to assume that humans are somehow resistant to this acid specifically on the inside and out, or else we just die.

The acid in the Alien movies is VERY unrealistic. For one thing acid is consumed when it reacts with stuff. It can't react with a larger amount of matter than it has itself. Spilling a cup of acid-blood would eat through a similar volume of dirt, but couldn't melt through the ground endlessly.

Another aspect of acid is that the "melted" matter gets converted into gasses and doesn't just disappear. Plenty of strong acids make some really nasty gasses when they react with stuff.

Yet another aspect of acidic reactions is that they get hot. The faster the reaction, typically the hotter it gets. Some extreme acids bust in the flames when they come in contact with things you don't normally think of as flammable, like glass and concrete.

So consider what would happen if you spilled acid-blood on some dry leaves and branches? You might literally start a forest fire. Spill some blood on the wrong materials and you could suffocate yourself with poisonous fumes.

What would happen if someone stabbed you? Your blood would rapidly dissolve the blade, heating up the rest of the tissue around the stab wound. It would also create a large volume of gasses that would probably cause damage to the surrounding tissue as well. There would also be a bunch of random metallic compounds seeping into your bloodstream from the reaction, which would be fun.

Instead of primitive weapons that caused damage to people by poking holes in them and letting blood drain out, getting impaled with something might cause you to literally explode.

So some other random changes that acid-blood society would have are:

No surgery at all, tools melt explosively when they cut you.

Medicine / biology would be MUCH more difficult to study, how are we even supposed to inject you with anything? How would you dissect a cadaver?

Warfare would have looked a lot different. The most durable armor would be made from stuff that resists the acid-blood... like human tissue.

Menstruation would be rather unfortunate for everyone.

Childbirth would be MUCH more messy

Anywhere that people might bleed would need good ventilation

Mosquitos are either much more or much less of a problem

Dead bodies would probably be disposed of in oceans / major waterways

Structures and vehicles would have much fewer sharp edges

Overall fighting would probably be much more serious

No tattoos or piercings - scarification would probably still be prevalent

Contracts signed in blood would be harder to store properly

"Blood-fire" extinguishers would be common safety equipment

Manufacturing processes that require a strong acid would be cheaper, so that's nice.

Things would be interesting to say the least.