# Human Acid Blood And... Jail

Tags: alternate-reality, law-enforcement

Inspired by this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N0jaxb94Fc), the question arose what today's Law enforcement would look like if humans (Homo sapiens sapiens) had blood that is so acidic that it eats through all matter. The only exception to this is the human bloodstream (and a metal/stone deep under the earth, which is unknown (sorry but mass murder/suicide does not let the earth collapse)). Everything else is normal.  The human being is not restricted in his normal functioning (no injuries, no diseases) with the acidity in the blood.

Only the blood vessels are immune to the acid but it can be assumed that the blood can close smaller wounds fast enough so that the surrounding tissue does not suffer irreparable damage. Skin decomposes in longer contact ( ~5 min) with the blood.

I would equate the strength of the acid with that from the Alien movies.

I learned after my [first failed attempt](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167643/human-acid-blood)  that violence on a person with acidic blood has a lot of nasty side effects, from heat to gases to the danger of explosion.

**EDIT:**

I see three major problems here:

**locking up a person who can open any lock with a nosebleed**

**make this possible without fixing the person completely**

**and the problems that arise when transferring the solution to a larger prison building**

**How can I solve this ?**

Bonus problem:

How can I prevent the prison from blowing up if a fight/ stabbing with the notorious sharpened toothbrushes escalates and a chain reaction (of exploding people) occurs?

Comment: 3 questions plus a bonus question, while we have a 1 question per post policy... please fix it.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica  instead of asking a general question (like "how would Law Enformenct evolve"), I thought it would be better to split the problem out a bit so that my intention of the question could be better understood

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need acid-proof rock. IIUC, acids work via *chemical* reactions, not magic. The process of dissolving stuff neutralizes the acid. Blood won't just keep dissolving stuff until it reaches the Earth's core, it will keep dissolving stuff until *it is used up*. An entire corpse worth of blood probably isn't enough to dissolve the rest of the corpse (unless you are *completely* ignoring physics), let alone eat a hole kilometers deep.

Comment: @Matthew in the back of my mind I had something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_suicide)  , concentrated in one place, it would surely go deep

Comment: If your blood dissolves "stuff" at a volume ratio of approximately 1:1, and you could concentrate it in an area 1cm², it would take about *a million* people to reach the center of the earth. *If* you could prevent the sides of the hole from collapsing... which, once you hit magma, you definitely *can't*. Seriously, if your acid follows physics at all, I'm pretty sure you're okay. (Alternatively, your "metal/stone deep under the earth"... is just plain old magma.) [Note](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScifiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside how completely implausible the premise is (we'll call the acid blood magic):

## Put 'em in an Oubliette

The problem here is the idea of a prison as *cages*, with locks.  All you have to do is put people somewhere from which escape is physically impossible without assistance.  So, a deep hole with sheer or reverse-sloping walls.

If you want to be able to make your dungeon multi-story, you could also put your prisoners in cages 3 stories up suspended by chains (and repeat as necessary).  That they can dissolve the lock is irrelevant if all that wins them is a short drop and a sudden stop.

The hole is the simple solution, though.  Maybe they could tunnel out, but they don't need acid blood [to do that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shawshank_Redemption).  That's why you'd still need guards.